# php preg_match's equivalent in C++ with Boost?

Tags: php, c++, regex, boost

I have the following working php code:

```
preg_match('/^(\d+):/', $string, $matches)
```

However, When I try to do it in C++ using Boost's regex library, it's not working.

```
regex expression1("^(\\d+):"); 

std::string filename = "C:\\Users\\root\\Desktop\\something.bin";
std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), 
std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

cmatch what; 

if(regex_match(contents.c_str(), what, expression1))  
{ 
    cout<<"value is "<<what[1]<<endl;
}
```

And I can't figure out why. The `regex_match` works fine with other patterns but not with this one `^(\\d+):`.

Comment: Boost is a library for C++, not C.

Comment: @develroot: "Still not working" is not useful. Provide a complete, minimal testcase that demonstrates the issue. I'd guess that your input string is different.

Comment: @develroot: I didn't ask for "the full code". I asked for [a testcase that demonstrates the issue](http://weegen.home.xs4all.nl/eelis/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml). How are we to know what's inside your "C:\Users\root\Desktop\something.bin"?

Comment: @develroot: Where is the line in that file that should match the regex? I don't see one. (And I didn't ask you to dump the entire file on us, but for a **testcase**!)

Comment: I also note that your input file is about torrenting mp3 files for which I'm sure you don't have a distribution licence. I probably won't be commenting on this question further.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal this is a random sample.

Comment: @develroot: You complain that the pattern doesn't match, and the only evidence you provide is an input file with no lines that _should_ match. I don't think I can help you further.

Comment: ahh..sorry didn't notice that the first character was not processed by php

Comment: @develroot: The process of creating a testcase would have revealed this to you, and you would not have had to ask at all! Basic debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      | Single quotes |  Double quotes |
 -----+---------------+----------------+
  PHP |   string      |     string     |
      | (verbatim)    |                |
 -----+---------------+----------------+
  C++ |   char        |     string     |
 -----+---------------+----------------+
```

Your use of single quotes in PHP means the `\d` doesn't take on its special meaning.

However, you correctly use double quotes in your C++ (you have to, since in C++ single-quotes delimit chars, not strings). But now you have to consider the special meaning of the token `\d`.

Escaping the backslash will solve your problem:

```
regex expression("^(\\d+):");
```

And you'd have to do this in PHP too if you used a double-quoted string:

```
preg_match("/^(\\d+):", $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character begins an escape in a C string. Try `"^(\\d+):"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Using a backslash inside a string means that the backslash needs to be escaped.

Try `"^(\\d+):"` (two backslashes)

**Edit**: As Berry comments, `\d` inside a PHP single quoted string is totally legal. I mistakenly thought that it was actually a violation, but one that PHP "helpfully" fixes for you automatically.

Comment: Hi. In PHP this is not true, as long as you use *single* quotes around the string. Only in double quotes will you have to escape characters, the single quotes means literal string.